# Remove namespace from a specific node, use the result for 2nd xslt(version1.0) transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, multipass

I am a newbie on XSLT and I am finding the concept bit difficult to grasp; any book or link suggestion?

I am trying to remove the namespace from customerinfo node and all its child nodes i.e. customerinfo,name and age. After the namespace has been removed i want to use the resulting xml as a input for other xslts?

XML 1:

```
    <uc:cpy xmlns:uc="http://oldcompany.com">
     <customerinfo xmlns="http://oldcompany.com" xmlns:d="http://test" Cid="1004" fid="aa">
        <name xmlns="http://oldcompany.com">Matt Foreman</name>
        <age xmlns="http://oldcompany.com">26</age>
     </customerinfo>

     <uc:prodcut xmlns="http://oldcompany.com" xmlns:d="http://test" >
        <uc:item>Hammer</uc:item>
        <uc:quantity>1</uc:quantity>
     </uc:prodcut> 
    </uc:cpy>
```

XML 2: after removing namespace; leaving the attribute value as-is:

```
    <uc:cpy xmlns:uc="http://oldcompany.com">
     <customerinfo Cid="1004" fid="aa">
        <name>Matt Foreman</name>
        <age>26</age>
     </customerinfo>

     <uc:prodcut xmlns="http://oldcompany.com" xmlns:d="http://test" >
        <uc:item>Hammer</uc:item>
        <uc:quantity>1</uc:quantity>
     </uc:prodcut> 
    </uc:cpy>
```

Finally, pass the xml 2 as input for other xslt template imports on the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to remove the namespace from customerinfo node and all its
>   child nodes i.e. customerinfo,name and age.

If you know in advance the names of all child (or descendant) nodes of `customerinfo`, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:uc="http://oldcompany.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uc:customerinfo | uc:name | uc:age" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise do something more general like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:uc="http://oldcompany.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::uc:customerinfo]" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that both methods assume that attributes are *not* in a namespace (i.e. can be just copied).

---

> Finally, pass the xml 2 as input for other xslt template imports on
>   the document.

That's a task for your calling application, not something you can do in XSLT itself. I am not sure why you need to do this in two steps to begin with - why not write a single stylesheet that does it all?